# Custom arcade expression to change the colours of text labels on an ArcGIS Online web map?

Tags: arcade, arcgis-online-webmap

I have a web map where I am labelling the point features with the values in 2 different text fields (eg."id"-"operation type").  I'd like to change the colour of the text for the "id" field label to make it easier to distinguish on the map. Can this be done using an arcade expression?

Answer (score 2):

I think the short answer is no. If you search the geonet forum there is much debate about lack of support in the Arcade language for [labelling in Collector](https://community.esri.com/ideas/12988-support-arcade-expressions-in-collector) and [colouring of fonts](https://community.esri.com/ideas/13567-generate-different-label-stylescolors-based-on-different-attribute-value-in-arcgis-online). I would imagine this functionality will come in some future release.